# Data from Excel does not show up in Bar Chart

Tags: excel, charts

I am trying to create a bar chart using data imported from Excel. This is how my excel file looks like.

[image: Excel File]

I created the following function:

```
    compareDIF[a_, b_] := (
dados = Import[a];
lateCondCC =dados[[b, 2, 4]];
lateCondEN = dados[[b, 2, 5]];
lateCondER = dados[[b, 2, 6]];
lateExtCC = dados[[b, 3, 4]];
lateExtEN = dados[[b, 3, 5]];
lateExtER = dados[[b, 3, 6]];
testCC = dados[[b, 4, 4]];
testEN = dados[[b, 4, 5]];
testER = dados[[b, 4, 6]];
BarChart[
{
lateCondCC, lateCondEN, lateCondER,
lateExtCC, lateExtEN, lateExtER,
testEN, testER,
},
ChartStyle->{{Black, White, Gray}},
BarSpacing->{0.4, 1.0},
ChartLegends->{{"Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"}},
PlotRange->{{0.3,9},{-0.3, 0.5}},
Frame->{False, True, False, False},
FrameLabel->{{"Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 3"}, "label"},
Ticks->{False, False},
GridLines->{{2.8, 4.8}, {0.0}},
GridLinesStyle-> Dashed,
ImageSize->550
]
);`compareDIF[a_, b_] := (
dados = Import[a];
lateCondCC =dados[[b, 2, 4]];
lateCondEN = dados[[b, 2, 5]];
lateCondER = dados[[b, 2, 6]];
lateExtCC = dados[[b, 3, 4]];
lateExtEN = dados[[b, 3, 5]];
lateExtER = dados[[b, 3, 6]];
testCC = dados[[b, 4, 4]];
testEN = dados[[b, 4, 5]];
testER = dados[[b, 4, 6]];
BarChart[
{
lateCondCC, lateCondEN, lateCondER,
lateExtCC, lateExtEN, lateExtER,
testEN, testER,
},
ChartStyle->{{Black, White, Gray}},
BarSpacing->{0.4, 1.0},
PlotRange->{{0.3,9},{-0.3, 0.5}},
Frame->{False, True, False, False},
Ticks->{False, False},
GridLines->{{2.8, 4.8}, {0.0}},
GridLinesStyle-> Dashed,
ImageSize->550
]
);
```

However, when I try running this function, Mathematica returns a bar chart with no data, such as this:

[image: Bar Chart]

I would like to know why my code is not showing the data. I know this must be a very basic question, but I cannot find what I did wrong.

Thank you

Comment: What about debugging it step by step? Have you tried to see what exactly does `{lateCondCC, lateCondEN, lateCondER...` contain?

Comment: show how you use it. is `b=1` ?

Comment: I use b = 4 because the data is on the fourth sheet of my excel file. I use it like this: data = compareDif['file path', 4]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is actually the case that the file you are trying to `Import` is laid out *exactly* as shown in the attached screenshot then evaluating something like `Import[<path to file>]` *should* return the following:

```
{ 
  { 
    {"", "", "", ""}, 
    {"", "", "", ""}, 
    {"", "Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 3"}, 
    {"Group 1", 1., 2., 3.}, 
    {"Group 2", 3., 2., 1.}, 
    {"Group 3", 1., 2., 3.}
   }
  }
```

Notice how `Dimensions[%]` evaluates to `{1, 6, 4}`; this means that in   function `compareDIF[a_, b_]`-*assuming* `a` stands for the path to the file, which it should, since it is the only argument in `Import[a]`-`b` is in all probability *redundant* or defaults-manually-to `1` .

Given the `Dimensions` of the imported expression, it seems that the *third* index in the `Part` expressions *must* reference its *rows* while the *second* index is used to represent the *columns*; provided all this is correct, the variables `...Cond...` correspond to the *first* column of data, the variables `...Ext...` correspond to the *second* column of data and lastly the `test...` variables correspond to the last column of data.

If my guess is correct, then I think that the following template should help you obtain the result you're opting for-with appropriate adjustments:

```
BarChart[
  Transpose[Drop[Drop[impt[[1]], 3], None, 1]],
  ChartLabels -> {{"Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 3"}, None},
  ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, {"Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"}],
  ChartStyle -> {Automatic}
 ]
```

> [image]

(in the place of `Automatic` you can put eg `Black, White, Gray` and use the rest of the `Options` you prefer-`impt` above stands for `Import[a]`)

*ps*. in the initial code, the lists containing the variables in `BarChart` had a trailing `,` which probably didn't help.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what the problem is. When asking Mathematica to import data from Excel, I was indexing the wrong way. In my Excel file, the variable Time 1 in Group 1 is in cell B4. If the second index in Part expressions must reference its rows and the third must reference its columns, then the indexing should be [[1, 4, 2]] in order to retrieve data from cell B4. I was doing the opposite of that - lateCondCC =dados[[b, 2, 4]], which retrieves data from cell D2. Since this is an empty cell, no data appears on my bar chart. Thanks for the help!